# JShint warning: jQuery plugin marked incorrectly 'defined but never used' in AMD

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd, jshint

JSHint is throwing a "jQueryPlugin is defined but never used" error on the declaration of jQueryPlugin.

How do I tell JSHint to either ignore this specific error or define jQueryPlugin in a way JSHint understands.

```
    define([
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'backbone',
        'some-jquery-plugin'
    ], function ($, _, Backbone, jQueryPlugin) //here is the error
    {
        'use strict';
        var someView = Backbone.View.extend(
        {
            someFunction: function ()
            {
                $('#a-css-id').jQueryPlugin();
            },
        });
        return someView;
    });
```

Things I've tried

`/* exported jQueryPlugin */` exports statement at top of file dose not work for this (been suggested in other questions)

`/* jshint unused:false*/` works, but makes the rule global in the file (2000+ lines of code) so I don't see it as a workable solution.

`/* jshint ignore:line */` is apparently not enabled in build system - so I cant commit this change (grunt-contrib-jshint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to just remove `jQueryPlugin` from the list of arguments:

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'backbone',
        'some-jquery-plugin'
    ], function ($, _, Backbone) 
    {
```

Two reasons:

1. You do not use that value. (You use `$(...).jQueryPlugin`, which is *different*.)
2. I've loaded many jQuery plugins with RequireJS and never encountered any plugin that returned a useful value *as a module*. They all install themselves on `$` and typically return `undefined` as their module value.

Comment: This seems strange to have more modules passed in then module handles, but it works - so jQuery modules (and other modules that don't return a value) must be listed last? I was always under the (obviously incorrect) impression that each module needed a passed in argument.

Comment: Modules that don't return a value do not *have* to be listed last but it is useful to list them last in the dependencies so that you can just omit the corresponding parameters for them in the function you give to `define` (or `require`). This, by the way, is just taking advantage of how JavaScript generally works. You can call *any* function with more parameters than the number of parameters defined, which is exactly what happens if you call `define` (or `require`) with an array of dependencies which has more elements than the number of parameters declared on the function.